# VB.Net Query For MYSQL Query finding in set

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have a table 'Users'
that consists of 
ID
Name
BranchAccess
Username
Passwordd

now in BranchAccess i put the ids of the branches
BranchAccess = 2,3,11

how can i query that in vb.net?
that will be like this

```
+----+----------+----------+------------------------+
| id | username | password | BranchAccess(varchar)  |
+----+----------+----------+------------------------+
|  1 | bob      | ******** | 1,3,11                 |
|  2 | mary     | ******** | 2,8,5                  |
| .. | ........ | ........ | ...................... |
+----+----------+----------+------------------------+
```

```
QueryConnect = "SELECT * From users Where BranchAccess=@BAccess"

CommandConnect = New MySqlCommand(QueryConnect, DataConnection)

CommandConnect.Parameters.Add("@BAccess", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SBIDLabel.Text
```

Comment: You should avoid working with CSV this way, and instead just use `WHERE BranchAccess IN (2, 3, 11)`

Comment: thanks for your help guys i was able to use it by using this

QueryConnect = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET(@BAccess, BranchAccess)>0"

Comment: You should _really_ create a `BranchAccess` table that links the `UserID` with the `BranchID`. Then it's a simple query with a proper `JOIN`. That's how relational databases work.

Comment: @daShier Duly noted bro i will look into it ^_^

Comment: You should be using a second table for those multi-values.

Answer (score 1):

just swap your `parameter` and `column` and use `IN` keyword.

```
QueryConnect = "SELECT * From users Where @BAccess IN (BranchAccess)"
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=PqFvfCQ7r9)

Comment: Thanks for this bro will come very handy

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For Your Answer Guys i was able to find a solution using this

```
QueryConnect = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET(@BAccess, BranchAccess)>0"

CommandConnect = New MySqlCommand(QueryConnect, DataConnection)

CommandConnect.Parameters.Add("@BAccess", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SBIDLabel.Text
```